# What are the minimum requirements for releasing a package into the ROS distro for the first time

Tags: ros-lunar, tutorial, bloom-release, release, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am editing the question to more accurately reflect what I am trying to understand. I want to know what what the minimum requirements are for a package to be eligible for being incorporated into the ROS distro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288812/what-are-the-minimum-requirements-for-releasing-a-package-into-the-ros-distro-for-the-first-time./) by [ghendricks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34620/ghendricks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-16**:\

> I have not been successful in getting the package released

it would help tremendously if you could describe in a bit more detail what did not work, or what prevented you from releasing the package. It's not enough to state that you have not been successful.

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-17**:
@gvdhoorn is correct that we need more information to provide guidance. What steps of the tutorial yielded results you did not expect? If you saw errors, can you post the error text here for us to examine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what dimensions you're asking about. To be released into the ROS distro it basically just needs to be a well formed package.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0